# How to convert noise (Lwa db) for a particular distance?

Tags: noise

If default noise level is given, how can I calculate the noise level at a particular distance?

For example, if a generator says it's noise level is Lwa $99 ~\mathrm{db}$; how much noise level in  $~\mathrm{db}$ will be at $60 ~\mathrm{m}$ distance?

Comment: I can only hope that you won't harass sleeping people... 99 dB is extreme...

Comment: Well, I won't...but some people want to put a generator near a residential society, so I want to understand how it will affect the residents.

Comment: BADLY. It would require sophisticated sound isolation what he surely won't do! Our ears are working also logarithmically, it will be annoying from kilometers away!

Comment: Don't do it... in Germany, the police would the station shut down, because it doesn't have the required papers (which it surely couldn't provide). In my native country, the police would spit on the whole task, but unfortunate "accidents" would happen. And both of them had right, while you hadn't.

Answer (score 1):

Db, alias *decibel*, is a logarithmic unit and can it can measure power or amplitude. This time it measures probably amplitude.

The logarithmicity of the unit means in this sense, that if you give 10 to the dB, you get 3.162 times bigger amplitude. If you give 20 to it, you get 10 times higher amplitude.

Multiplying the dB value with anything doesn't have any sense.

Now you say the generator gives noise level 99dB and you want to know, what will be the noise 60m far away from it.

The problem is that you don't know, how far away gives the generator this 99dB. It is probably some standardized measurement what the writers of the technical documentation suspected well known, while it is not.

But, for example, if this 99dB would be 1m away from the generator, then 60m away you will have $\frac{1}{3600}$ smaller output (*only* *if* we are below free sky!) It is because the sound power is distributed on a 60 times larger sphere, which has a 3600 times bigger surface area.

In this case, you will get $log_{10}3600*2$, also around 7.11 dB loss. So, in this case, the result would be around 92 dB.

Comment: Are you sure it's 92dB at 60m? Because I read somewhere, you can reduce 6dB by each doubling of the distance. For example, if 99dB at 1m, 93dB at 2m, 87dB at 4m, and so on... so it's like somwhere around 60 to 65dB at 60m or so. What do you say?

Comment: @ShahzadLatif Wait, I check again. Until that you should check, how is this 99dB coming in the docs (how it is measured).